# A closed formula for the measure of the union of $n$ sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ and {${A_n}$}$_{i=1}^n$ is an arbitrary sequence of $\mathscr{A}$-measurable sets. I conjecture that 
$$
\mu\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n{A_n}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n{\mu({A_n})} -\sum_{i\neq{j}}\mu\left(A_i\cap A_j\right)+\ldots+ (-1)^{n+1}\mu\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n{A_n}\right).
$$ 
For the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ it is quite easy to verify it, but I don't know how to verify it for the general case.

Comment: Asked ten times on the site: integrate the identity $$\mathbf 1_{\bigcup\limits_i A_i}=1-\mathbf 1_{\bigcap\limits_i A_i^c}=1-\prod_i(1-\mathbf 1_{A_i})=\sum_k(-1)^{k-1}\sum_{|J|=k}\prod_{i\in J}\mathbf 1_{A_i}=\ldots$$

Comment: @Did can you prove it without using integrals?

Comment: It seems like a generalization of inclusion-exclusion principle. You can prove yours by mimicking a proof of inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: try a recursive proof

Comment: @Milad What for? This is by far the simplest and most powerful approach.

Comment: @Did the usual reason is that it is an exercise in a chapter preceding the definition of the integral.

Comment: @Did My measure theory book has stated measures before introducing integrals.

Comment: @UmbertoP. How sad, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @Milad -- what is your measure-theory textbook?

Comment: Measure theory by Cohn @uniquesolution

Comment: This really is just [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability).

Comment: I just did not want to open my combinatorics book, but I think now I have to @Chappers

Comment: @Milad Thanks. I never looked at this book, but apparently is is quite popular. It is very natural, and hardly sad, to start from measures and only then arrive at integrals, the reason being, that integrals are of measurable functions against measures.

Comment: @uniquesolution you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: The base $n=2$ step is easy to verify, as you've said. For the induction step, suppose that it holds for any $n$ sets, and observe that $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}A_k=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\cup A_{n+1}$$ and $$\bigcup_{k=1}^n\left(A_k\cap A_{n+1}\right)=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\cap A_{n+1}.$$ Now, apply the base result and the induction hypothesis.

Comment: I did not realize induction would help. thanks